# Isn't react-testing-library redundant with using a full render?

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a question about react-testing-library. It seems like this is the go to testing  library if you're doing hooks development since Enzyme doesn't seem to support hooks at this time and who knows if it will at least from the shallow rendering perspective... at least from what I've read at this time. So what is driving me a little crazy about react-testing-library is that it suggests doing full renders, firing clicks, changes, etc. to test your components. So what if you were to change the functionality of a Button component let's just say, are all the tests going to break that are using it? Doesn't it seem odd to render and run tests on every child component of that component when you're already testing that component? Are you expected to mock all those components inside a parent component? Doesn't it seem redundant to do clicks and changes if you're already doing that in automation testing such as using webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you test 'mission critical' things in end to end testing.
These test rely on lots of features all working together.
The entire APP running and every single piece of functionality in-between working.
Because they rely on so many thing and take so long to develop and run you don't want to test every thing with an end to end test.

And if it breaks, where did it break? which piece of functionality is no longer working?

If you change the functionality of a button that was used in and end to end test it would fail - as it should. But say the end to end test fails and your integration/unit tests on the button also fail? You know straight away where your problem is.

And what if you refactor the button so that it still functions the same but the code implementing this is much cleaner? Then you should design your tests so that they still pass and this is actually where react-testing-library really shines. 
You mimic how a use might interact with the component and what you expect the component to do - not what it's internal state is like you might in enzyme.

I'm not a professional developer though but that's my two cents.

Comment: OK... just trying to wrap my head around the concept. So is the goal to test the top level components that make use of the core/shared components so they're all tested in this manner as opposed to testing each core/shared components? Such as, just bypass direct testing with the Button component specifically, but test all use cases of those Button component scenarios, such as different classNames to change the look of the button, in higher level parent components that make use of them?

Answer (score 0):

You must take a look at the "Testing Trophy" philosophy that @kentcdodds talks about. - https://testingjavascript.com/

Like Michael mentions in the other answer, if you change the functionality of your Button components, your tests are expected to break. Tests are a clear translation of the business needs, so if needs change, your existing tests are supposed to break, so that the new ones may be incorporated.

On your point around doing automation testing instead, where I'm assuming you mean "end-to-end testing". This is different from the tests that `react-testing-library` suggests you to do. The philosophy asks you to write a good number of integration tests on your parent component, so that you can be sure that the way the parent component uses the child component is in harmony. It validates the configurations you made on the child component which are very specific to the behavior of this parent component, and hence the integration tests.

Comment: OK... that's making better sense. So essentially, I wouldn't really need to have a test file for the button component specifically because I'm testing all of its use cases in the components that make use of it? If that's the case, I'm guessing the jest coverage would tell me if there were missing cases for that button component. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Those tests should be enough, but that shouldn't stop you from pure unit testing your button as well. Maybe this button has a feature that none of your components currently use. So, I'd not suggest against testing these individual child components.